# UK patent, early publication risk for PCT?

Tags: pct, uk, early-publication

The UK offers 'accelerated publication', aka early publication. Will a publication of a UK national patent, after for example 9 months, pose any risk for a PCT application based on this patent, submitted in the allowed 12 month window for converting a national patent to a PCT application?

Answer (score 2):

Good answers here are expected to be longer than one word. In this case the answer is the one word no.

Comment: Funny, but it should probably still be "No, because the priority right dates the PCT filing back to the first filing, unless you add new subject matter in which case etc." Enough for, well, 2-3 sentences ;-)